# getIntent().getExtras() sometimes crashing in Activity

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, crash

I start an Intent with some extras and read the passed extras in the Activity's `onCreate`

```
class MyActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        val extras: Bundle? = intent.extras // <-- crash
        val someInt = extras?.getInt(EXTRA_SOME_INT, -1) ?: -1

        // ...
    }

    companion object {

        const val EXTRA_SOME_INT = "someInt"

        fun createIntent(context: Context, someInt: Int) =
            Intent(context, MyActivity::class.java).apply {
                putExtra(EXTRA_SOME_INT, someInt)
            }
    }
}

// Activity started like this:
fun startMyActivity(context: Context) {
    context.startActivity(MyActivity.createIntent(context, 1234))
}
```

This works fine, however, in production, the marked line sometimes causes the app to crash when `getExtras()` is called. According to documentation it can be nullable, but it shouldn't throw an exception.

The crashlog is not always the same, but either this happens in `BaseBundle`:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.os.Parcel.dataSize()' on a null object reference

BaseBundle.java line 164 in android.os.BaseBundle.<init>()
Bundle.java line 106 in android.os.Bundle.<init>()
Intent.java line 6580 in android.content.Intent.getExtras()
```

... or this happens:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
Duplicate key in ArrayMap:

BaseBundle.java line 126 in android.os.BaseBundle.<init>()
Bundle.java line 102 in android.os.Bundle.<init>()
Intent.java line 5756 in android.content.Intent.getExtras()
```

The crash happens only on Android 5, 6 or 7. I haven't found a way to reproduce it on my own device.

Is there something I do wrong, or what would be the best way to avoid this crash? Without the extra bundle, I cannot display my Activity.

Comment: Check if getIntent() returns null before use. Dont let your app crash.

Comment: @blackapps getIntent() doesn't cause the crash, it is never null in an Activity's onCreate. The internal calls of getExtras() cause the NullPointerException

Comment: Ok. But anyhow you can catch those exceptions so your app does not crash. Display a toast to inform the user. Maybe a restart?

Comment: And how about the intent to start your activity? Is it done well?

Comment: @blackapps yes, catching and exception and simply finishing the activity would be my last resort if I don't find the cause of the issue.
I updated the question with the code that starts the Intent

Comment: `"someInt"` That is a string literal. No int.

Comment: Not very sure about this, but this issue was caused by a race condition in `BaseBundle` while trying to write to parcel and unparcel
, which has been fixed in 2016, after Android 7.

Comment: @SaurabhThorat that would explain why it stops happening after Android 7. Do you perhaps have a link to that issue? I couldn't find a bug which was acknowledged by google

Comment: @blackapps you're saying "`"someInt"` That is a string literal. No int." well yes, that's how a key-value pair works - OP is passing in a STRING key and an INT value.

Comment: Have you seen `extras?.getInt(EXTRA_SOME_INT,...`? Think you have to put an int then. Not a string @a_local_nobody

Comment: @blackapps why would you put an int if you're already trying to get an int ? that's not how a key value pair works, i'm not sure i understand what you're saying :) there's nothing wrong with the code OP is using, you can literally type that into your own IDE and see that it's fine, if it wasn't fine it wouldn't even compile ?

Comment: @Day This is the commit which might've fixed this issue: https://cs.android.com/android/_/android/platform/frameworks/base/+/694753465b577509cecba33a90fb7cb6d50f5533

Comment: @a_local_nobody, yes it will compile fine of course. The compiler does not know what was put in. But at runtime.. if you try to get an int and it was a string.. Maybe you are right .. i only tried to give some suggestions to OP to find the cause.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was a bug in AOSP which was [fixed](https://cs.android.com/android/_/android/platform/frameworks/base/+/694753465b577509cecba33a90fb7cb6d50f5533) after Android 7. Here is the reason in the commit message:

> **Fix for race in writeToParcel and unparcel**
>
> Don't access the parcelled data while it might be recycled by another
> thread.
>
> Also make a local reference of mMap, which could be modified by
> another thread.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. Then I will simply wrap my code in try/catch and finish the activity in case the error happens.
If I get any more insights why this crash got more frequent in my latest release, I will post it.

Answer (score -1):

```
    Bundle receiveData = getIntent().getExtras();

    if (receiveData != null){
        .....
    }
```